# Using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication library to generate Access Tokens for resources other than Azure Services

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

We are using the `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` for generating token for connecting to KeyVault (in local it is using the signed user context from Visual Studio and in Cloud its generating token from MSI in Azure Web App).

I was wondering if I can use the same library for generating bearer tokens for connecting to other custom APIs.

Scenario - I need to consume data from an Upstream API which is protected by an AAD App (in the same tenant). Currently, I am using an AAD Client ID and Client Secret to generate the token (using the Active Directory Identity library). I was wondering if I can use the `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` library to generate the token.

Comment: you can use the `ADAL` or `MSAL` libraries to obtain a token for apps protected by AAD. Otherwise, the library itself does not generate the token but call an endpoint to get the token.

Comment: Using ADAL library I can always generate the token, but then I will have to maintain the Client Secret with me. I was looking for an option where I can use the  `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` library to delegate the management of secrets.